# Excel: How to keep some cells blank

Tags: excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet to which I am adding data on an almost daily basis.  It is very simple--the variable just goes into the cells in column B and various formulas spit out results in subsequent columns.  Here is the issues, in all of those other columns, I prefer that the columns remain blank until there is a number in the B cell.  Right now, the formulas take an empty B cell as a 0 and go ahead a spit out a result.  What can I do to keep those blank, even though the formula is there ready for data, until something is imputed?

Answer (score 2):

You can use ISBLANK function + IF condition to achieve this.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A3),"",A3+15)
```

This formula adds 15 to A3 only if A3 is not blank.

Answer (score 0):

In your formula, you can check the value of column B:

```
=IF (B2 <> ""; B2 * 2; "")
```

Comment: Unbelievable, I also multiplied by 2 in my answer. My variant was: =IF(ISBLANK(B1);"";B1*2)

Comment: Okay . . . sorry if I'm dense.  Here is my first actual formula.  =(B5-B6)*-1  What do I need to change it to in order to make it work?

Comment: `=IF (B5 = ""; ""; IF (B6 = ""; ""; (B5-B6)*-1 )) `